# How can I convert the following SQL query to run in entity framework?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and learning making queries. Can anyone please help me how can I convert the following SQL query to run in entity framework?

```
select max(isnull(TInvoice.InvoiceNr, 0)) + 1 
from TInvoice inner join TOrders 
on TInvoice.OrderId = TOrders.OrderId 
where TOrders.ClientFirmId = 1
```

Comment: It would help if we could see your data model...

Comment: @Liath what info You need Regarding Data model?

Comment: Take a look at http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Comment: An idea of the table, property and association names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments have said, without the data model it is hard to be exact.
Would really need to see how you have defined your relations in your data model.

I guess from first read my first impression is something along the lines of:

```
int max = context.TInvoice.Where(x => x.TOrders.ClientFirmId == 1).Max(x => x.InvoiceNr);
```